# Are DOM events triggered from a Chrome extension propagated in the main page’s context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I’m trying to write a Chrome extension that programmatically sends a click event to a particular link on the page. This particular link has known click event handlers on the page that I can see with Chrome’s web inspector.

I’m sending this click event with a jQuery `.click()` in a `content_page` script in my Chrome extension, but it looks like the handlers are not firing. When console-logging the result of the jQuery `.click()` call, I can see that the expected return value is coming back, so I know that this code is actually running.Ch

I know that this jQuery code works, as I can paste this same line in Chrome’s console in that page and get the result I expect.

Am I crazy in thinking that I can trigger DOM events from the extension’s `content_page`? I know that the `content_page` executes in a separate environment, but I was pretty sure that triggered DOM events were bubbled through both environments.

(If I’m not crazy, how would you proceed in debugging?)

Comment: Can you give a minimal example to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES – click events *do* propagate, but there’s something odd happening when I target the DOM element I want to send a `.click()` to with jQuery, but it works when using native DOM traversal functions like `getElementsByClassName()`.

Mystery solved: just use vanillaJS approaches to call `click()` on the DOM element itself instead of the jQuery-wrapped version.

Comment: The problem is not solved by using DOM traversal methods. It's solved by using VanillaJS's `click()` method instead of jQuery's `.click()`. `$('body')[0].click();` would also work.